# Path-related errors with TexLive2011

Tags: errors, texlive

I was playing around with the path settings in tlmgr and the following error came up:

```
Updating symlinks ...
Executing action path add
Can't exec "kpsewhich": Too many levels of symbolic links at /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 588.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFSYSVAR in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 588.
Can't exec "kpsewhich": Too many levels of symbolic links at /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 589.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFSYSCONFIG in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 589.
Can't exec "kpsewhich": Too many levels of symbolic links at /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 590.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFLOCAL in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 590.
Completed.
```

The original default paths were:

[image]

Now I cannot access tlmgr or in fact compile using Latex packages at all.  Please help me to revert changes and regain functionality of TL2011.

I'm using Ubuntu 64 bit, Xfce.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that you enabled the option "Create symlinks in system directories" which is a bad choice for the installation. You shouldn't enable this option in the main manue.
If you are a member of TUG (which is anyway a good choice :-) then you can read Enricos article on installing TeXLive on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?  What are symlinks?

Comment: e.g. a link for `pdflatex` inside `/usr/bin/` into the original directory `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/.../`

Comment: The error refers to "Too many levels of symbolic links..."  - now what does this mean?